# Why is noncentral t-distribution for sample size determination for small sample?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

For sample size determination for small sample, population distribution of which is normal, the test statistic $$T = \frac{\bar{x}-\mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}, ~~~\text{where $\mu_0$ is null value}$$

is considered under the assumption of the alternative hypothesis $\mu = \mu' \gt \mu_0$.
Since $T$ follows **noncentral** $t$ distribution, chart or table is used to determine sample size $n$ with desired type II error.

The above is typical explanation available in statistics text books.

Now I'm curious what's wrong with the following reasoning:

If we assume that the alternative hypothesis $μ=μ′$ is correct $T = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu'}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ should follow $t$-distribution by the same argument that $T = \frac{\bar{x} - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ follows $t$-distribution when  $μ=μ_0$. Then we can proceed on to calculate

$$
Pr(\frac{\bar{x}-\mu'}{S/\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{\mu_0 + t_{\alpha, n-1}s/\sqrt{n} - \mu'}{s/\sqrt{n}}) = \beta(\mu')~~~\text{(*)}
$$

to determine sample size n that satisfies the required $\beta$.
noncentral t-distribution cannot be involved at all.

Specifically, if my assumption that $(\bar{x}-\mu')/(s/\sqrt{n})$ follows t distribution is correct, we can simply set:

$$
\frac{\mu_0 + t_{\alpha, n-1}s/\sqrt{n} - \mu'}{s/\sqrt{n}} = t_{\beta(\mu')}
$$

and solve for $n$. No need to summon noncentral t distribution, no need to use $\beta$ curve to find $n$

=================================================================
With help of @BruceET, I found my silly mistake.

The equation to determine a rejection region is

$$
Pr(\frac{\bar{x} - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}} > t_{\alpha, n-1}) = \alpha
$$

From this I wrongly thought the rejection region in terms of $\bar{x}$ is

$$
\bar{x} > \mu_0 + t_{\alpha, n-1}\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

This is wrong because $s$ itself is a random variable and therefore cannot be included in the bounds. If it were, I could have argued the eq.(*) could be used to calculate power for the alternative hypothesis.

Comment: This approach indeed works and it's actually the approach that I've personally learned.

Comment: Puzzled by last phrase about not using noncentral t distribution.

Comment: @BruceET, I made some elaboration.

Comment: Numerator of t statistic (under whatever assumption $H_0$ or $H_a)$ must be standard normal in order to have (regular) t dist'n. In particular, it must have $0$ mean. Mean of numerator for noncentral t is non-centrality parameter.

Comment: I think, simply put, my question boils down to why (x¯−μ′)/(s/√n) does not follow t distribution. or If it is t distribution where else I am making mistake. Under the new assumption,  x¯ is again a normal distribution and when it is subtracted by a new mean it becomes zero mean normal.

Comment: If you change from $\mu$ tp $\mu^\prime$ in numerator than you've changed the t-statistic and with it the rejection region. // Can you show how your approach gives correct power (or Type II Error probability)? Say using my example?

Comment: Suppose if we set up a new null hypothesis but this time using $\mu'$ as null value, the value that was used for alternative value in the original question. Then what distribution would you say $(\bar{x}-\mu')/(s/\sqrt{n})$ follow? Wouldn't that be t-distribution with df n-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma).$ Suppose you want to test $H_0: \mu=10$ against $H_a: \mu > 10$ at the 5% level of significance when $n = 16.$

Then the t statistic for this test is
$T_0 = \frac{\bar X - 10}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ and $H_0$ is rejected if $T_0 \ge t^* = 1.753,$ where $t^*$ cuts
probability 5% from the upper tail of Student's t
distribution with $\nu =n-1 = 15$ degrees of freedom:
$\mathsf{T}(\nu=15).$ Computation in R.

```
qt(.95, 15)
[1] 1.75305
```

The power $\pi(12) = P(\mathrm{Rej}\, H_0\, |\, \mu = 12)$ against the specific alternative $\mu_a = 12$ is

$$\pi(\mu_a) = \pi(12) = P\left(\frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}}\ge t^*\,|\mu_a=12\right)
= P\left(\frac{\bar X - \mu_a + (\mu_a - \mu_0)}{S/\sqrt{n}}\ge t^*\,|\mu_a=12\right)\\
= P\left(\frac{\bar X - \mu_a + 2}{S/\sqrt{n}}\ge t^*\,|\mu_a=12\right)
= P\left( \frac{ Z + \delta }{ \sqrt{V/\nu} } \ge t^* \right),$$
where $\delta = \sqrt{n}(\mu_a-\mu_0)/\sigma = 2\sqrt{n}/\sigma,\,$
$Z \sim\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ and $V = \nu S^2/\sigma^2
\sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu).$

That is, by definition,  $\frac{ Z + \delta }{ \sqrt{V/\nu}}\sim \mathsf{T}(\nu, \delta),$ Student's noncentral t distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and noncentralty parameter $\delta.$

In particular, for our example, $\delta = 2\sqrt{16}/\sigma.$
For $\sigma = 2,$ we have $\delta = 4$ and $\pi(12) = 0.985.$

```
1 - pt(qt(.95, 15), 15, 4) 
[1] 0.9848477
```

The following simulation in R gives essentially the same power. With a million iterations one
can expect three-place accuracy.

```
set.seed(1128)
pv = replicate(10^6,  t.test(rnorm(16, 12, 2), 
               mu=10, alt="g")$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.984809
```

*Ref:* Except for notation, parts of the above parallel Sect 2.3 of Bain & Englehardt (1992), *Intro. to Probability and Math. Stat.,* Duxbury, p400.

Comment: thank you for the clear and detailed explanation about how noncentral t distribution arises in this context. But what I'm really curious about is why my alternative reasoning is wrong. Dasherman said in his comment that he had no practical issue in taking the alternative approach but the two approaches seem conflicting in theoretical point of view.

Comment: Good. I confess I don't follow the logic of your last equation and the claim that the noncentral t distribution is not involved. And I don't see how to get the right answer using it. // I'll have to let @Dasherman explain his/her comment.

Comment: Thank you @BruceET. The conversation with you and your equations helped me realize where my mistake was. Thanks again!